# SugarCRM Befor_save hook

Tags: php, hook, crm, sugarcrm

I use SugarCRM and i try to make a Hook when someone save a opportunity.

This is the situation:

I have the column "Opportunity Amount" and i want to calculate the column "Montant %".

So i have add twoo ligne in the hook:

```
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1,'calcul montant heure','custom/modules/Opportunities/calcul.php','calcul','montant');
```

I add the class file:

```
<?php

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class calcul
{
    var $module = "Opportunities";
    function montant($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        $bean->Montant_perc = ($bean->amount_usdollar * $bean->Probability (%))/100;
    }
}
?>
```

it does not work but I do not understand why?

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code directly into the question instead of screenshotting.

Comment: Done, it's easier to read

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to recheck the fields name that you are using in before_save logic hook method becuase it seems to me that you are using field labels instead of field names i.e i think

```
$bean->Probability (%)
```

should be

```
$bean->probability
```

and as the field saved in db is generally in small letters so you should also check that the field

```
$bean->Montant_perc
```

should  be

```
$bean->montant_perc
```

After making these modification do a Quick Repair and then resave the Opportunity to trigger before_save logic hook